# How to disable the superscript rule in markdown?

Tags: markdown

I'm trying to get MathJax on my page that has Markdown code as well. So whenever I use `^`, Markdown renders it as superscript and this causes problems with MathJax. How do I disable the superscript rule on my HTML home page?

Their documentation has this code to disable a particular rule or list of rules.

```js
var md = require("markdown-it")().disable(list, ignoreinvalid);
```

What is the name of the superscript rule? Can I add this code in a script tag on my home page?

Comment: There is no superscript rule in Markdown. Maybe markdown-it adds something like that, but it's not standard.

Comment: Superscript is not a standard markdown feature. Which implementation are you using?